# tcsh: How to change the file extension for multiple files?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, tcsh

Is there a one line command in `tcsh` to change the extension of a set of files?  In the various DOS shells, I used to use the following:

```
ren *.abc *.def
```

This would rename all files ending in `.abc` to end instead with `.def`.  In `sed` terms this would perform something like the following:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\)*\.abc$/\1.def/'
```

on the file names.  I could probably throw bits and pieces together to achieve something similar in *nix, but I'm guessing that the issue here is my lack of experience with `tcsh`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type in these four lines. After the first the prompt, tcsh will tell you that you are inside the `foreach` loop.  You could also turn it into a shell script and call that shell script.

```
foreach n ( `ls *.abc` )
set base = `basename $n .abc`
mv $n $base.def
end
```

Comment: No need for an intermediary variable, see brainiac's answer

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what others have said, many UNIX flavors provide a command called "`rename`".  If your goal is to rename files using `tcsh`, specifically, then this won't help you.  Otherwise, you can achieve your goal with:

```
rename abc def *.abc
```

It's a very simple-minded and very useful command.  In the list of files provided by the 3rd argument, it replaces all occurrences of the 1st argument with the second.  At least in the versions I am familiar with, there is no pattern matching at all, except to the degree that your shell will expand patterns in the list of files for the 3rd argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, could I rename files like `*-r.pk` to `*.pk` without having `rename` identify `-r` as an option?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if `tcsh` provides an easier way to do this, but here's what I usually do:

```
ls *.abc | sed 's/\(.*\)\.abc/mv "\1.abc" "\1.def"/' | sh
```

I have also written a Python script called `regexmv` that renames files using regular expressions. Here's the script:

```
import os
import re
import sys
import os.path

def main(argv):
    dry_run = True
    if argv[0] == '-f':
        dry_run = False
        argv = argv[1:]

    pattern = argv[0]
    repl    = argv[1]
    files   = argv[2:]

    max_length = max([len(f) for f in files])

    for f in files:
        new = re.sub(pattern, repl, f)
        if f != new:
            if not os.path.exists(new):
                print "%s --> %s" % (f.ljust(max_length), new)
                if not dry_run:
                    os.rename(f, new)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I first run it like this:

```
regexmv '\.abc$' '.def' *
```

to see which files will be renamed (and how they will be renamed), and if this is what I want, I run it like:

```
regexmv -f '\.abc$' '.def' *
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach f (*.abc)
mv $f $f:r.xyz
end
```

Comment: This is the correct tcsh (not bash) idiom to do this, and I have confirmed that it works in tcsh

Answer (score -2):

[Collating answers - what the questioner got from the responses]:

There is no easy way to change a group of files' names in tcsh.  Chas. provided the simplest solution in tcsh, but it still wasn't easy.

The best way to do what I'm after if you're using tcsh as your shell is using the external rename command (see Eddie's answer).

I appreciate that this is not what I actually asked in the question - but what I learnt is that my question was wrong!

Thanks to everybody that replied, your answers were very helpful - each in a slightly different way.  If somebody would like to summarise the results of this question in a better way than I have, please do.  I'd much prefer to give my "accepted answer" to somebody else!

Comment: Incorrect: if you have a variable `set foo=foobar.baz`, you can `echo $foo:r.ext` to get `foobar.ext`. And then it's just `foreach f (*)` and then you can refer to `$f` in the foreach loop. (ending it with `end`). See brainiac's answer.

Comment: `:r` is a 'colon-modifier', documented in freebsd's tcsh man page, with other similar modifiers in the 'history substitution' section. It gets the 'root name' of a filename, literally accepting that it's the part before the first period in the filename.